# How to retrieve Product Version?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, versioning, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to retrieve the product version of an ASP.NET 5 web application?

This is what I have in my `project.json`:

```
"version": "4.0.0-alpha1"
```

How would I be able to retrieve this from within the application? I used to be able to do this on older ASP.NET versions:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

However, now it just gives me `0.0.0.0` all the time. Any ideas?

Comment: Either use `IApplicationEnvironment` or copy the implementation from it https://github.com/aspnet/PlatformAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions/DefaultApplicationEnvironment.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject IApplicationEnvironment anywhere you need the version. So for instance in the Configure method of the Startup class:

```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(applicationEnvironment.ApplicationVersion);
        });
    }
```

Source: "Services Available in Startup" http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/startup.html

Comment: What version are you talking about? This answer was given with RC1. And with RC1 my answer gives the version as specified in project.json. It even says so in IntelliSense: "gets the version of the application, as specified in the project.json file". With RTM IApplicationEnvironment doesn't even exist anymore and you have to use IHostingEnvironment (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html). Your downvote is uncalled for.

Comment: The problem is that `IHostingEnvironment` doesn't have `ApplicationVersion` member.

Comment: I know. But again, this was the answer with RC1. If you want to know how to do it with RTM, then ask a new question. Or are people required to revisit their answers whenever a new version comes up? Please let me know, then i know for sure I'll stop answering.

Answer (score 6):

Add a reference to `System.Reflection` in your project.json file if you don't already have one.

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-23516" // Current version at time of posting
}
```

Then, you can get the value from the [AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) `InformationalVersion` property.

```cs
private static string GetRuntimeVersion() =>
        typeof(SomeClassInYourAssembly)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .Assembly
            .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
            .InformationalVersion;
```

Comment: This is not the correct way. Please consider my answer.

Comment: This also works for non-ASP apps, eg. console application.
However I prefer to get assembly from `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` instead of `typeof(...).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`

Comment: jesus christ, after a week of searches for an answer. this works for .Net Core 1.1. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a command line application with .NET 6, I found this to work.

(Anything using the Assembly Location seems to fail when the application is published to a self-contained file.)

First, set the version (in this example: 1.4.3) in the properties: (search for "version")
[image: Setting the version in properties]

Then use this code to get the number you put in:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
```

```
var version = typeof(Version) // "Version" is the name of any local class
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .Assembly
        .GetCustomAttributes<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
        .First()
        .InformationalVersion;
```